# Empty SPO Recycle Bin ignore Treshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, recycle-bin, threshold

I am trying to delete a SharePoint Online recycle with more than 1,000,000 list items in it.

```
Clear-PNPrecycleBinItem -URL $siteURL
```

It is throwing an error on the limit of 5000 list item threshold.

Even `Get-...` isn't working.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, we have 5000 as the hard limit for list view threshold in SharePoint online. Unlike SharePoint on-premises, this threshold limit can't be increased.

Solution: empty list items in batch by using CSOM method.

SharePoint Online: How to Get All List Items from Large Lists ( >5000 Items):

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/12/sharepoint-online-get-all-items-from-large-lists-powershell-csom.html

SharePoint Online: Empty Recycle Bin using PowerShell:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-empty-recycle-bin.html

Comment: Hi Lisa. Thanks for this answer but this doesn't seems to work. Somehow I'm not capable to combine those two scripts into one.